# Monit reports certificate self-signed issues after upgrade

Tags: monit

After an update to last binary version of Monit, Monit reports an issue about

```
SSL server certificate verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, prevois version of Monit was not using the public binaries but compiled locally. Compiling locally Monit from sources solved the issue.